# What was the first website to be created specifically to promote a movie?

Tags: first-appearance, marketing

I'm trying to figure out what the first instance was of a website being created specifically for a movie. I've narrowed it down to *Star Trek: Generations* (1994) and *Stargate* (1994).

I was pretty sure it was *Star Trek: Generations*, because I had it from a couple of sources, but then, after a little bit more googling, I found that people make the same claim for *Stargate*.

According to IMDB, *Star Trek: Generations* was released in November 1994 and *Stargate* in October 1994. I don't believe the fact that *Stargate* was released first necessarily means that the website was too.

#### For *Star Trek: Generations*:

- From IMDB trivia: "The first movie to have a web site created specifically to promote it."
- http://movies.trekcore.com/generations/originalsite/generationswebsite.pdf

#### For *Stargate*:

- From IMDB trivia: "This was the first movie to ever have an official website. It was set up by Dean Devlin in 1994 and featured images, trailers and behind the scenes clips and actor information."
- http://www.omgfacts.com/lists/12986/Stargate-was-the-first-movie-to-have-an-official-website

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although it was obviously quite close between them, I believe the answer to the question is that the *Stargate* website came before the *Star Trek: Generations* website.

Although there are lots of pages and references to both sites as being first, I have only been able to find a single reference for either of them that includes a date.

From the *Star Trek: Generations* entry on the Memory Alpha website:

> The official website for *Star Trek: Generations*s, created on 28 October 1994, was the first site on the internet to officially publicize a feature film. [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Generations#Official_Site)

While this quote does state that *Star Trek: Generations* came first, the launch date for the website happens to be the exact same date that IMDB states the *Stargate* movie was released (October 28, 1994). Given that the *Stargate* website was created as a promotional tool for the movie, it stands to reason that it would have been launched before the movie was released (i.e. October 28, 1994).

Answer (score -2):

It's probably *Stargate*. The registration record for `startrek.com` lists 1995-02-27 as the creation date and for `stargate.com` as 1986-08-05.

This date corresponds not to the movie *Stargate*, but to the much earlier TV show "The Adventures of the Galaxy Rangers" in which one of the episodes involved finding a "Stargate."

Comment: Sorry, why does that mean it's probably Stargate? I mean, if that registration date corresponds to a tv show then it doesn't really shed any light on the Stargate movie v's Generations debate does it?

Comment: Yes it does. Since the domain name was in use very early, it is more likely the film makers became aware of it before the movie was even released and took action to control it, because otherwise it would cause confusion with the movie. Since startrek.com was not registered until 1995, that would suggest it was later.

Comment: Ok yeah, I can see your logic there. There's a lot of assumptions though. I think I'm actually getting closer to deciding it's Generations, because I've been able to find more actual references to it being the first dedicated movie site than I have for Stargate. Stargate I've only been able to find one liners from third parties.

Comment: If you're going by domain registrations, you're implicitly ruling out web sites of the form `http://startrek.paramount.com/` or even `http://www.paramount.com/startrek/` both of which currently exist. Those types of URLs would have been more common than the `http://www.startrek.com/` type in the early days of the web. The DNS really was a hierarchy once. It wasn't always a flat namespace with `.com` stuck on the end.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Subdomains generally still have semantic meaning, even if the internal implementation differs from how it was in the past.

Comment: FWIW, the earliest archive of the [http://www.stargate.com/](http://www.stargate.com/) domain is [November 11, 1998](https://web.archive.org/web/19981111191257/http://www.stargate.com/) and seems too be the home to: “This site Copyright (c) 1998 by Stargate Information Services.  All rights reserved.” The [contact page](https://web.archive.org/web/19990128131013/http://www.stargate.com/contact.html) even says, “The name Stargate is a very popular name. You have reached the web site of Stargate Information Services, a former provider of UUCP domain names and Netnews via satellite.”

Comment: Given that http was introduced in 1991, and stargate.com related to a company providing UUCP and usenet services, it's pretty clear this had nothing to do with a single episode of a TV show.  I doubt the existance of an unrelated domain-name played any difference in the timing for which  movie first had any sort of website.